# WCF concurrency model confusion

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm reading this msdn page which says the concurrency model defaults to single: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.concurrencymode.aspx

Yes this page makes it seem like a new instance is created per client: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx (see per-call services heading):

> "Per-call services are the Windows Communication Foundation default
>   instantiation mode. When the service type is configured for per-call
>   activation, a service instance, a common language runtime (CLR)
>   object, exists only while a client call is in progress. Every client
>   request gets a new dedicated service instance."

Am I reading this wrong?

BTW I am hosting my WCF in a windows service.

Is it single or multiple?

Answer (score 3):

There's a good explanation of what's going on over on CodeProject.  Here is the URL:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/89858/WCF-Concurrency-Single-Multiple-and-Reentrant-and

Long story short, it's a combination of both InstanceMode and Concurrency.  The default setup is to use a PerCall for InstanceMode and Single for Concurrency. The net effect:

- A new instance of the object servicing your requests is created for each call to the service (**PerCall**)
- Your service will only use one thread to service requests at a time (**Single**).

Don't confuse this with InstanceMode = Singleton and ConcurrencyMode = Multiple or Reentrant, in which one instance serves multiple requests on multiple threads.

Answer (score 2):

look at this article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx

"In PerCall instancing, concurrency is not relevant, because each message is processed by a new InstanceContext"